How to use native replication with SSL in managed PostgreSQL?
Currently e.g. psql only supports SSL connections by
loading SSL certificates from files on disk.
But for example in cases where I need to create a logical replication subscription from a managed PostgreSQL instance, I can't put certificates on disk.
Can I somehow connect to instance A via psql and tell it to make subscription to instance B using inlined SSL cert values that I passed to psql?
I found that golang PostgreSQL client support this. 

Have you tried using sslmode=require?

Is this about the psql client or the postgres replication client?

@Bergi Main problem is being able to use native replication with SSL in managed PostgreSQL really.

Then I'd suggest removing psql from your question title

I think the problem is that even if we had inline SSL parameters for that one CREATE SUBSCRIPTION command, then under the hood SUBSCRIPTION possibly contains multiple SSL connections to the replica over an undefined amount of time.
And how does PostgreSQL know what SSL parameters to use without commiting those parameters into long term disk. That's the reason why inlining SSL isn't supported in PostgreSQL
